# How to demonstrate your ability to publish in high-impact venues? (Application form)

Tags: application, postdocs, job-search, job, faculty-application

I was applying for a postdoc position and I came across this sentence.

> Please provide examples of when you have demonstrated your ability to publish in high-impact venues

This one is confusing and a bit redundant because they previously asked me about my experience in fields X and Y. So, I don't know how to address this question without mentioning (again) my experience in the fields X and Y. All I did, is deliberately avoid, in the previous question, talking about my publications in journals and conferences. Any ideas about this? Do the examples they're talking about are: my publications in journal A and a conference B?

Comment: The phrasing of their sentence seems a bit odd. I don't see how one could answer that question without giving examples of published papers in high-impact venues, and at this point they could just ask for a list of papers in high-impact venues.

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking. I think that these sentences are automatically generated from the job description or something. There other sentences that also ask for the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal way to "demonstrate your ability" is by stating that you've successfully done it. So, an optimal answer to this question would be along the lines of:

> I have published 12 papers in top-tier journals and conferences, including the Annals of Mathematics, Physical Review Letters, and the International Conference on Machine Learning. My h-index is 65 and 4 of my papers have been cited over 1000 times each. I am already pursuing many additional lines of research that will let me continue this rate of publication.

Now if your publication record is less impressive, you might not be able to give a strong answer like the above, but you'll still have to make the best case possible that you will be able to produce several top-tier publications if they hire you. This is different than the previous questions, which focused more generally on your skills, interests, and experience.

Comment: ... And I have a number of potentially productive relationships going with collaborators.

Comment: Mmm interesting, unfortunately I don't have an impressive publication record like that, I just defended my PhD... But that gave me an idea about how to write my answer..